# Django REST framework get selected values from complicated json

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have complicated json, I want to get only part of information from it and store it to db. Are serializers (Django REST framework) way to go? Consider something like following:

`{"top_level":{"detail1":"info1", "detail2":"info2", "detail3":{"deeper_detail1":"deeper_info1", "deeper_detail2":"deeper_info2"}}}`

For example I would have Car model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    car_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The 'car_type' should get value from 'detail2' (that is info2), 'car_state' should get value from 'deeper_detail2' (that would be deeper_info2).

Only idea I got is this:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('car_type', 'car_state')

    def get_car_type(self, obj):
        return obj["top_object"]["detail2"]

    def get_car_state(self, obj):
        return obj["top_object"]["detail3"]["deeper_detail2"]
```

It seems django doesn't agree with me so I wonder if this is the right path to begin with. Can I do something like that with serializers in Django REST framework?

Comment: Where do you get this complicated json from? Rather than sending complicated json in the request data, first parse it there, wherever it is coming from and then, send the proper json - `{"car_type": "info2", "car_state": "deeper_detail2"}`. Or, if you cant change the request data with the complicated json, then parse the request data in the view and then initialize the serializer with the proper json

Comment: JSON source is not under my control, I hoped to find a way around parsing it "manually" in view. I do that in python script (that I am upgrading to django app) and I hoped to find something more elegant. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'd need to parse the complicated JSON first into something the ModelSerializer will understand.

One way to achieve this is to override `to_internal_value()` in your serializer, and parse the complicated JSON there before passing it up to the base implementation:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    return super().to_internal_value({
        'car_type': data['top_object']['detail2'],
        'car_state': data['top_object']['detail3']['deeper_detail2']
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the django way to do it. Regarding your code - it will overwrite class instance method and by using method on super class it ensures the right data format?

Comment: Yes exactly. By overriding the superclass method it is able to intercept the data and parse it into something more usable. Once parsed, it then passes it up to the superclass for normal processing - such as validation etc.

Comment: What if `car_type` is foreign key reference? I get `car_type` name from json, but I need to find it's id from `CarType`  table to use it as foreign key, right?. I tried `selected_car_type = CarType.objects.get(name=data['top_object']['detail2'])` and assign it as before `'car_type': selected_car_type.id` but `serializer.is_valid()` returns `False` and `serializer.data` seem to ignore `to_internal_value` method.

Comment: That sounds correct, although for `serializer.data` you should override [`to_representation()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj) which is responsible for turning an object into a dict. As far as `is_valid()` is concerned, can you see why this is returning `False`? You should be able to inspect `serializer.errors`

Comment: `serializer.errors` is some real powerful magic, got it working now, thanks :)